# rails producing separate css files in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails version 6.0.3.2, but I started to notice that when precompiling asset:

```
rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get  my public/assets filled with all my css files separated (as they are in development) and minified in addition to application.css

Is this something new or there is something wrong? I have no idea why this is happening!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it will always build them independently, then assemble them into a unified file if so requested. It doesn't trim the individual files after. The individual files are just a byproduct of the compilation process.

You only need the combined asset pack for deployment, the individual files can be ignored.